# What command/invocation is used to generate NCBI 16SMicrobial blastdb

Tags: blast

I'm looking for the exact invocation used to generate the 16SMicrobial database that you can download from here:

https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/blast/db/

I'm hoping to create the same type of blastdb with the same type of metadata with custom sequences.

Platform isn't an issue, but let's say on ubuntu 14.04 or 16.04.

I would like to replicate the creation of the database as closely as possible. 
 The most important feature is the taxonomic information as can be seen [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK279688/):

> The databases on the FTP site contain taxonomic information for each
>   sequence, include the identifier indices for lookups, and can be up to
>   four times smaller than the FASTA. The original FASTA can be generated
>   from the BLAST database using blastdbcmd

Creation of a blastdb using makeblastdb from a set of a fasta sequences is not an issue and can be achieved via:

```
makeblastdb -in <your_file.fasta> -dbtype nucl -out <database_name>
```

My question is specifically about the invocation NCBI uses to add the metadata that is present in the NCBI's 16SMicrobial blast database as I am keen to make sure I have replicated the process as closely as possible.

Comment: What properties, specifically?

Comment: Most crucially the taxonomic information, but I would like to replicate this creation of this database as closely as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Running `blastdbcmd -db foo -info` provides a little information but I haven't seen anything which will report exactly how a blastdb was created.

A [blastdb readme](https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/blast/documents/blastdb.html) suggests that only the `parse_seqids` option has been added to the standard parameters.

> For those from NCBI, the following makeblastdb commands are recommended:
>
> - For nucleotide fasta file:   makeblastdb -in input_db -dbtype nucl -parse_seqids
> - For protein fasta file:      makeblastdb -in input_db -dbtype prot -parse_seqids

The `-parse_seqids` requires NCBI fasta headers in the correct format (spec can be found [here](http://ncbi.github.io/cxx-toolkit/pages/ch_demo#ch_demo.id1_fetch.html_ref_fasta)).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what specific properties you are considering. As far as I know, that's just a normal blast database, like any other. These are produced using the `formatdb` command which is part of the `ncbi-blast` software. You haven't specified what system you are using so I can't help you find and install it, but the command will be something like:

```
formatdb -p F -i yourSeqs.fasta -n yourDBName
```

- `formatdb` : the command
- `-p F` : protein: false. This is needed to make databases of nucleotide sequences.
- `-i yourSeqs.fasta` : your input file with all your sequences in fasta format.
- `-n yourDBName` : the name (choose whatever you like) for your database.

You can then use `yourDBName` as a database to blast against. The above assumes yuou are

Comment: I would recommend using the newest ncbi-blast+ suite instead of the (now deprecated?) legacy-blast. In that cases `formatdb` would become `makeblastdb`, with slightly different arguments.

Comment: @mgalardini that sounds very reasonable. I'm afraid I'm showing my age. This is the only one I've ever used but I last did so more than 10 years ago now. Please post an answer with this new tool you mention. I'm sure it's the Right Way© to go today.

Comment: @terdon - whatever works I say ;).  Thanks for the help, I've updated the question to make it (hopefully) more clear.  I am specifically looking to add metadata to a blastdb and looking for a reference or similar for what metadata is added to the 16SMicrobial database.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether you are looking for how to produce taxonomy file or rep_set file (qiime reference file types). But you can produce fasta file (rep_Set) like that:

```
$blastdbcmd -db 16SMicrobial/16SMicrobial -outfmt '%f' -entry 'all' > 16SMicrobial.fasta
```

Then you can create QIIME-compatible id_to_tax maps with this code:
https://github.com/mtruglio/QIIME_utilities/blob/master/id_to_tax_mapmaker.sh

Hope this helps.